# Parsing MSigDB Supplementary Collections

Tags: r, file-formats, format-conversion, pathway

MSigDB recently added [Supplementary Collections](http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/supplementary_genesets.jsp). The formatting is similar to the original MSigDB gene sets, but there is an additional `metadata.txt` file ([link](http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/supplemental/scsig.v1.0.metadata.txt)).

It looks like (condensed for easier reading):

```
STANDARD_NAME   Fan_Embryonic_CTX_Big_Groups_Cajal_Retzius
ORGANISM    Homo sapiens
ORGAN_SYSTEM    Central Nervous System
PMID    29867213
PUBLICATION_TITLE   Spatial transcriptomic survey of human embryonic cerebral cortex by single-cell RNA-seq analysis
AUTHORS Fan X,Dong J,Zhong S,Wei Y,Wu Q,Yan L,Yong J,Sun L,Wang X,Zhao Y,Wang W,Yan J,Wang X,Qiao J,Tang F,
GEOID   GSE103723
...
STANDARD_NAME   Fan_Embryonic_CTX_Big_Groups_Brain_Endothelial
ORGANISM    Homo sapiens
ORGAN_SYSTEM    Central Nervous System
PMID    29867213
PUBLICATION_TITLE   Spatial transcriptomic survey of human embryonic cerebral cortex by single-cell RNA-seq analysis
AUTHORS Fan X,Dong J,Zhong S,Wei Y,Wu Q,Yan L,Yong J,Sun L,Wang X,Zhao Y,Wang W,Yan J,Wang X,Qiao J,Tang F,
GEOID   GSE103723
...
STANDARD_NAME   Fan_Embryonic_CTX_Big_Groups_Excitatory_Neuron
ORGANISM    Homo sapiens
ORGAN_SYSTEM    Central Nervous System
PMID    29867213
PUBLICATION_TITLE   Spatial transcriptomic survey of human embryonic cerebral cortex by single-cell RNA-seq analysis
AUTHORS Fan X,Dong J,Zhong S,Wei Y,Wu Q,Yan L,Yong J,Sun L,Wang X,Zhao Y,Wang W,Yan J,Wang X,Qiao J,Tang F,
GEOID   GSE103723
...
```

I could not find any description of the formatting. Is this a standard format? Is there a parser for it (preferably in R)? It looks like I can just transpose each record to get it in a table format, but I don't know if I can trust all records to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to separate each set, you can do something like this

```
dat <- readLines("~/Desktop/scsig.v1.0.metadata.txt")
dat <- gsub("\t"," ",dat)

# get the indeces of each type
standardName <- grep("STANDARD_NAME",dat)
organism <- grep("ORGANISM",dat)
organSystem <- grep("ORGAN_SYSTEM",dat)
pmid <- grep("PMID",dat)

# return the values 
standardName <- gsub(pattern = "STANDARD_NAME",replacement = "",dat[standardName])
organism <- gsub(pattern = "ORGANISM",replacement = "",dat[organism])
organSystem <- gsub(pattern = "ORGAN_SYSTEM",replacement = "",dat[organSystem])
pmid <- gsub(pattern = "PMID",replacement = "",dat[pmid])

df <- data.frame(standardName,organism,organSystem,pmid,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 head(df)
                                     standardName      organism             organSystem      pmid
1      Fan_Embryonic_CTX_Big_Groups_Cajal_Retzius  Homo sapiens  Central Nervous System  29867213
2  Fan_Embryonic_CTX_Big_Groups_Brain_Endothelial  Homo sapiens  Central Nervous System  29867213
3  Fan_Embryonic_CTX_Big_Groups_Excitatory_Neuron  Homo sapiens  Central Nervous System  29867213
4              Fan_Embryonic_CTX_Big_Groups_Glial  Homo sapiens  Central Nervous System  29867213
5       Fan_Embryonic_CTX_Big_Groups_Brain_Immune  Homo sapiens  Central Nervous System  29867213
6          Fan_Embryonic_CTX_Big_Groups_Microglia  Homo sapiens  Central Nervous System  29867213
```

This method is very verbose, but it's a start and it can be easily improved with a loop.

```
 #---- EDIT
```

Not knowing how the format works, there may be two issues:

1) gene sets with missing values only

```
STANDARD_NAME Aizarani_Liver_C33_Stellate_cells_2
ORGANISM 
ORGAN_SYSTEM 
PMID 31292543
```

2) gene sets with missing value and type

```
STANDARD_NAME Aizarani_Liver_C33_Stellate_cells_2
PMID 31292543
```

`Case 1` is not an issue, as the code above will simply add an empty cell and go to the next line.
For `Case 2` we can use `unique` to get a list of all define types, create an empty `data.frame` with those `types` and have a loop (or `sapply`) to add the values in the right columns.

We can check the nature of `metadata.txt`:

```
 types <- gsub("^(.*)\t.*$","\\1",dat)
 sapply(unique(types), function(t) length(grep(t,types)))

     STANDARD_NAME                ORGANISM            ORGAN_SYSTEM                    PMID       PUBLICATION_TITLE 
                257                     257                     257                     257                     257 
            AUTHORS                   GEOID            EXACT_SOURCE    EXTERNAL_DETAILS_URL                    CHIP 
                257                     257                     257                     257                     257 
      CATEGORY_CODE             CONTRIBUTOR         CONTRIBUTOR_ORG       DESCRIPTION_BRIEF RAW_PUBLICATION_MEMBERS 
                257                     514                     257                     257                     257
```

Your are lucky and you don't have to worry about shifting because of missing values. 
There is a fixable issue with `CONTRIBUTORS`, but it is related to the `regex`, not the file format.

Comment: That should work, but if any of the records are missing a field, then they will be shifted.

Comment: I didn't think of that. To avoid this issue, you could get the list of all the types (`STANDARD_NAME`, `ORGANISM`,...), use `unique` to avoid repetition and create an empty `data.frame` with those columns. When you return the values, you can check the type and fill the right column. I will try to update my answer when I have some time.